# where can i find the sourceMap files that uploaded by the webpack-sentry-plugin

Tags: sentry

Sincerely hope for help

i use webpack-sentry-plugin to upload the sourceMapfile, but where can i find files On the server path。

I have built a sentry service myself.

sentry workpiece do not display any content.

If I don't delete sourceMap file, sentry can show me the correct error code location,
but i unsafe。

when i try to delete sourceMap file， sentry't can show me the correct error code location,

look like webpack-sentry-plugin does't work.

Sincerely hope for help, thank you for give me help！